# Sum inputs of form with JQuery

Tags: jquery, sum

I'am trying to sum all the inputs of a form, but instead of this it's adding them.

Like if one input is R$1,44 and the other R$21,09, the result is 1.4421.09

Can someone help me out?

```
$('#lista').on('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
var qtd_itens = $('#lista tbody').children('tr').length + 1;
somatotal = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < qtd_itens; $i++) {
    acho = new String($(':input[name="qtd' + $i + '"]').val()),
    alto = new String($(':input[name="preco' + $i + '"]').val());
    acho = acho.replace(',', '.');
    alto = alto.replace('.', '');
    alto = alto.replace(',', '.');
    var v = '';

    if (!isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto)){
        v = parseFloat(acho*alto,2);
    }
    $(':input[name="total' + $i + '"]').val(formatter.format(v));
    somatotal += v;
    $(':input[name="valortotal"]').val(somatotal);
}
});
```

Comment: Use parseFloat for all form fields values.

Comment: Why don't you declare `v` as a number instead of a string? E.g. `var v = 0;`?

Comment: that solved my problem... thanks.. didn't notice that i was declaring as a string.. thanks a lot

Comment: Cool. I posted the comment as an answer, so can you please accept the answer if that solved your problem? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring `v` as a number instead of a string. E.g. `var v = 0;`